# "Set" with "where exists" performs better then without

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, exists

I come up by chances to this curious case.

Environment:

- Oracle 12.2.2
- Involved 2 tables.
- N. of rows 16 milions

As far I know, and reported here [Oracle / PLSQL: EXISTS Condition](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exists.php) the use of `where exists` is in general less perfomant of other way.

In my case however when updating a table's column with the value with another on join condition with the exists, the query run in about 12-13 sec without issues(I did only some check, as I really do not know all the content of the table):

```
update fdm_auftrag ou
set (ou.e_hr,ou.e_budget) =  ( select b.e_hr,b.e_budget
                 from  fdm_budget_auftrag b 
                where b.fk_column1 = ou.fk_column1
                 and b.fk_column2 = ou.fk_column2
                 and  b.fk_col3 = ou.fk_col3 )
where exists ( select b.e_hr,b.e_budget
                 from  fdm_budget_auftrag b 
                where b.fk_column1 = ou.fk_column1
                 and b.fk_column2 = ou.fk_column2
                 and  b.fk_col3 = ou.fk_col3  );
```

instead without the exists, it takes so much time then I even interrupt it.

I am just gessing as the condition in exist is valuated as a boolean, if the enginee found out at least one row, then had to do less touch on the DB, but I am not sure about it.

It is correct this "guess", have someone a more clear explanation?

Comment: Furthermore, the article that you link to is simply incorrect. The correlated subquery does not have to be executed once for every row in the driving table, and the optimizer can use a hash semi-join to do this very efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `where` clause is limiting the number of rows being updated.

Fewer updated rows means that the `update` query runs faster.  There is a lot of overhead to updating a row, including stashing away information for roll-back purposes.

I am assuming that you are updating relatively few rows in a much larger table.  If the `where` clause is selecting most of the rows, then there might be no performance difference.

And, finally, the two queries are not identical.  Without the `where` unmatched values will be assigned `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I am not sure why the 2 queries are different and why without the exist the enginee assign the "Null" value as it have to update column value only on the set condition anyway. Moreover the condition in the same for both subqueries

Comment: After few checks I reliyed that without "where exist" condition there would be updating with null value on unmatched rows. Thank you @Gordon Linoff